# Send mail without MTA, GMail, etc

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

Why doesn't it seem to be possible to send mails from the command line without any kind of SMTP server? All solutions that I found either use sendmail, postfix, etc. (those are SMTP servers as far as I understand it) or send it over GMail or some other provider (which needs authentication). Why can't an application just connect directly to the target mail server? For example, if I want so send a mail to user@test.com, why can't an application just connect to test.com and deliver the mail directly without any kind of other server involved? Sure, it would be marked as spam, but I don't care about that. Did I misunderstand the SMTP protocol, did I just not find the right application or did really just no one bother to write such an application?

Comment: it can, and hopefully they use postgrey to trash your mail. you must use a queue which is why you must have an MTA somewhere and you must establish yourself as a valid sender.

Comment: `Why can't an application just connect directly to the target mail server?` - Plenty of applications have been written that do just that (Groupmail being just one example.). I have no knowledge or experience with programming but I'd be willing to bet that almost every programming language has a send mail function that doesn't rely on the use of an external SMTP server.

Comment: I've seen folks try this.  Once I saw a java app that tried to understand talking to mail servers.  They loosely followed some of the RFC's and disregarded many of them.  There are many use cases and conditions you will need to account for to be a general purpose email sending program.  Do you have a very specific use case you are going to code around and write your own MTA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **did really just no one bother to write such an application?**

**Now they did!**

As a follow up to my other answer where I suggest writing a Python script, I have now written a very basic python 3 script that can do this for you. I have tested it on both Linux (2 different distributions) and Windows, and it definitely sends mail from both to my gmail account, which yes, does end up in the spam folder!

It cheats a little by using `nslookup -type=mx <recipient_domain_name> 8.8.8.8` to do the nslookup (`8.8.8.8` is Google's public DNS server), but the script still works on both Windows and Linux - the results are just parsed slightly differently. The reason for this "cheat" is to save you installing a third party python library, although it does assume you have the `nslookup` command available in your path - which it usually is.

It would be fairly easy to add extra functionality for attachments, friendly names in To: From: message headers, etc. Also, all the mx servers that are found by DNS are stored in a list in priority order, but the script only attempts to send to the first one. It would be fairly easy to improve the script so that it checks the others in priority order in case of failure to reach the first one.

**Usage:** direct_mail_sender.py recipient@domain.com from@originator.com "msg subject" "msg body"

Enclosing the subject and body in "double quotes" ensures that you can include spaces between the words.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, sys, smtplib

mx_records = []
mx_values = {'pref' : 0, 'serv' : ''}

if len(sys.argv) < 5:
    print('\nUsage:\ndirect_mail_sender.py recipient@domain.com from@originator.com "msg subject" "msg body"\n')
    exit()

recipient = sys.argv[1]
domain = recipient.split("@")[1]
originator = sys.argv[2]
subject = sys.argv[3]
body = sys.argv[4]

print("From:   " + originator)
print("To:     " + recipient)
print("Subject " + subject)
print("Body    " + body)

p = subprocess.Popen('nslookup -type=mx ' + domain + ' 8.8.8.8', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    line = line.decode().lower()
    if line.find("mail exchanger") !=-1 :
        for char in line:
            if str(char) in "\r\n\t":
                line = line.replace(char, '')
        if line.find("mx preference") !=-1 :
            mx_parse = line.replace(' ', '').split(",")
            mx_values['pref'] = int(mx_parse[0].split("=")[1])
            mx_values['serv'] = mx_parse[1].split("=")[1]
        else:
            mx_parse = line.split(" = ")[1].split(" ")
            mx_values['pref'] = int(mx_parse[0])
            mx_values['serv'] = mx_parse[1]
        mx_records.append(mx_values.copy())

retval = p.wait()

def mx_pref_sortvalue(record):
    return record['pref']
mx_records=sorted(mx_records, key=mx_pref_sortvalue)

server = mx_records[0]['serv']

print("\nSending mail to: " + recipient + " via first priority MX server: " + server)

smtp_send = smtplib.SMTP(server, 25)
smtp_send.sendmail(originator, recipient, "From: " + originator + "\nTo: " + recipient + "\nSubject:" + subject + "\n\n" + body)
smtp_send.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was talking about. It is still not working for me because Google doesn't like my IP and blocks it right away instead of putting it into spam. But that would probably happen with an MTA as well. At least I know how it would be done now.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't know why Google gave me special treatment!

Comment: Sorry to resurrect a very old post but thank you, this works and I always wondered if you could even do this without a known webhost as a relay. I wanted to add that you can use a temp mail service like https://10minutemail.com/ or similar to test this. Worked fine for me because I guess they don't bother blocking random ips like the big boys do. You can also do this with raw text input via something like netcat: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/send_an_email_using_netcat.html

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You are wishing for a plain mail user agent while wondering about the purpose of a mail transfer agent. Both have their place.

Some applications sending mail connect via SMTP, some use `mailx` or `sendmail`  compatible commands. All some clients (MUAs) really need is a SMTP server that will relay for you, but it is worth understanding that MTA's existence.

A designated MTA of yours to relay your mail through has some benefits. Changing smtp.example.com something else is easier than updating every application configuration. It provides a better security posture when not every host sends Internet mail, and maybe you malware scan outgoing mail centrally.  Mail is more likely to be delivered when it can be queued up and sent again automatically.

Usually one of the popular MTAs or a third party service is used, as a general purpose MTA is complicated. Mail going to many different destinations is commonplace, as is the need for aliases and other features. A simple send to destination is possible, but the are reasons for the infrastructure in the middle.

Comment: I know what the purpose of an MTA is, I just think it is a massive overkill for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether anyone has bothered to write such an application. But is definitely possible and would be fairly easy. I'm sure a python script could do it. The application would need to use DNS to look up the MX records for the recipient domain. So for recipient@domain.com the MX records for domain.com would need to be obtained. Then simply connect to the server specified in the DNS results with the highest MX priority (the lowest number!) and attempt delivery. Failing that, attempt to deliver to the next priority, and so on.

Why not teach yourself python by writing a script to do the job! I would start by just accepting command line parameters for a single recipient, subject and single line body to keep it really simple. Then make it more complex by adding capability for multiple recipient, cc, bcc, multi-line body, attachments etc.

Starting points:

http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

Comment: Excellent  idea.   With Python you can certainly create a command-line program that takes the mail server as an argument.

Comment: In that case you would need to look up the MX record for the recipient domain manually. Why not have python do it? I included the DNS python link which shows how to do an MX lookup as the first example.